# How to group list of string arrays, java 8 or java 11

Tags: java, java-8

{username,order}
trying to group them by username.

```
List<String[]> orders = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] o1 = {"john, apple"};
            String[] o2 = {"john, Orange"};
            String[] o3 = {"jane , banana"};
            String[] o4 = {"jane, Orange"};
            orders.add(o1);
            orders.add(o2);
            orders.add(o3);
            orders.add(o4);
```

lets say if i have the folowing orders
and i want to get to this

```
List<List<String[]>> groupedOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    groupedOrders.add(Arrays.asList(o1,o2));
    groupedOrders.add(Arrays.asList(o3,o4));
```

so the result I am looking for is groupedOrders,like the above one or in a map, as long as the list of orders are grouped together how do I transform orders list above into groupOrders, I have tried to use map or streams but couldn't make it work.

Comment: By which criteria are you grouping? Even and odd? What happens with an odd amount of elements? Please explain

Comment: ohh sorry { username, order} i am trying to order them by user name which will be unique

Comment: Are the arrays always 2 elements long?

Comment: yes, always two elements

Comment: You shouldn't mix up arrays as Lists.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to group them or sort them?

Comment: group them, to get two Lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against using arrays, by using a custom class:

```
class Order {
    String username;
    String order;
}
```

I've omitted the getters, setters, modifiers and constructors, as these 2 fields are the main component of that class.

You can then have a `List<Order> orders` where you add all the orders, from there it's rather easy to group them by name:

```
Map<String, List<Order>> grouped = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getUsername));
```

If you only want the actual orders, like `banana`, `apple` and so on you can use this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Order::getUsername, 
        Collectors.mapping(Order::getOrder, Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

---

If you really want to use arrays as your input you may aswell use this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = Arrays.stream(orders)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a -> a[0], 
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your array `String[] o1 = {"john, apple"};` has only 1 element and you probably want something like `{"john", "apple"}`. Pay attention to quotes.

I would also recommend [@Lino's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869089/5108737) solution, but it can be done with arrays:

```
Map<String, List<String[]>> map = orders.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0]));
```